# Comment View my team drives in list format with Google Picker API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, picker, google-picker

If I insert the next line
.setMode (google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST)
in the code below, the Chrome Code Inspector shows me an error and I get no display !
If I put this line in comment my code works and I get the Picker display with team drives in the form of thumbnails.

I wish to have the display of the team drives in the list form ....
Does anyone have the solution ?

```
function OpenFolderTD (token) {

if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
// show all file types
var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView (google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
// with associated folders
.setIncludeFolders (true)
.setMode (google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST) - Does not work for TD in list mode!
// See team drives
.setEnableTeamDrives (true);


var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder ()
.addView (docsView)
.setLocale ('fr')
.enableFeature (google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
.enableFeature (google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
.setTitle ('Select file (s)')
.setOAuthToken (token)
.setDeveloperKey (DEVELOPER_KEY)
.setCallback (pickerCallback)
.setOrigin (google.script.host.origin)
.setSize (DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2, DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
.build ();
picker.setVisible (true);
} else {
showError ('Unable to load the file picker.');
}

} // function OpenFolderTD () {
```

Comment: Please include details about the error to help folks debug

Comment: The error code in the Chrome console inspector is : "userCodeAppPanel: 1 ReferenceError Uncaught: getOAuthToken is not defined
to HTMLButtonElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel: 1) "
I incorporate the complete code of my function in response to Martin Zeitler below.

Comment: @PeterC you have to use the PickerBuilder to get the picker - and then obtain the View from that customized picker. of course, any unknown variable would need to be known within the scope of the function. it might continue alike `var docsView = picker.DocsView (google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)` ...not instancing another picker.

Comment: I'm misunderstanding, sorry ! My code works perfectly, what I'm trying to do is to have the display of team drives in list format and not thumbnail when opening the window. A parameter to associate with "setEnableTeamDrives (true)" ??
Thank you for your follow-up and your interest

Comment: Struggling with the same thing. Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Hello, sorry, still no solution. I always post thumbnails !

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the [PickerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#PickerBuilder) - else you'll most likely cannot enable `Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES` for that picker...

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
    .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
    .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
    .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
    .setCallback(pickerCallback)

    /* this is not supported by the default pickers: */
    .enableFeature(Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)

    .build();
```

because the documentation reads ...

> DocsView.setEnableTeamDrives(boolean)
>
> Shows Team Drives and the files they contain.
>
> Note: Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES needs to be enabled when enabling this.

Comment: The function integrates well ".enableFeature (google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)". See my answer below.

Comment: The function fits well ".enableFeature (google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)". I completed my question with the complete function